# Unable to convert url params string to hash and then back to url string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

Input is a params string (Input format cannot be changed)

```
something=1,2,3,4,5&something_else=6,7,8
```

Expected Output:

```
something=1,2,3,4,5&something_else=6,7,8
```

What I am doing:

```
params = 'something=1,2,3,4,5'
CGI::parse(params)
CGI.unescape(CGI.parse(params).to_query)
```

And I am getting this as output:

```
something[]=1,2,3,4,5
```

When I did `CGI::parse(params)`
I am getting this : `{"something"=>["1,2,3,4,5"]}`

which is wrong because it is not an array, something is a string which is "1,2,3,4,5" but it is being converted as array when I did CGI parse.

The reason I need to do CGI parse is because I need to manipulate the url PARAMS.

Is there any other possible way where I can convert it in the right way and maintain the params format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CGI module is a complete dinosaur and should probably be thrown in the garbage because of how bad it is, but for some reason it persists in the Ruby core. Maybe some day someone will refactor it and make it workable. Until then, skip it and use something better like URI, which is also built-in.

Given your irregular, non-compliant query string:

```
query_string = 'something=1,2,3,4,5&something_else=6,7,8'
```

You can handle this by using the `decode_www_form` method which handles query-strings:

```
require 'uri'
decoded = URI.decode_www_form(query_string).to_h
# => {"something"=>"1,2,3,4,5", "something_else"=>"6,7,8"}
```

To re-encode it you just call `encode_www_form` and then force `unescape` to undo what it's correctly doing to handle the `,` values:

```
encoded = URI.unescape(URI.encode_www_form(decoded))
# => "something=1,2,3,4,5&something_else=6,7,8"
```

That should get the effect you want.